# Display an empty password field

Tags: forms

I have a password field which currently displays the current password. How can I force the input to be displayed as blank? From the documentation [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7), it seems that `#default_value` or `#value` don't work (so I can give them an empty string as a value). How can I do this?

Comment: That'll be your browser saving the password, Drupal doesn't get involved. Clear the saved passwords in your browser and it should disappear

Comment: Cleared cached, saved passwords and form data in Chrome, but the password is still shown in its input.

Comment: Easy test...open up the same page in another browser. Is the password still there?

Comment: @Clive, most modern browsers will honor the autocomplete attribute on forms and input elements.

Comment: @MPD Yeah I just saw your answer, I've already copied it into one of my utility modules...gracias :)

Comment: Autocomplete is set to 'off' from Drupal. Yes, it is there with other browsers, even with those that I didn't previously use to access the Drupal site.

Comment: Hmmm that's strange. If you've created this element yourself using the FAPI could you post the code?

Comment: The password field is created by the Drupal core and I only added some things to the $form array. It looks like this: `[#type] => password
    [#title] => Current password
    [#size] => 25
    [#access] => 1
    [#weight] => -5
    [#attributes] => Array
        (
            [autocomplete] => off
        )
`

Answer (score 2):

We have a client who runs a security scan that flags login forms that have autocomplete enabled, and have been using this solution for a few years now:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * Remove autocomplete from all user forms.
 * Based on http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/disabling-autocomplete-forms
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form_id, 'user_') === 0) {
    $form['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with unsetting autocomplete on either the input or the entire form. The password field is still not empty.

Comment: Not sure what is going on.  This approach has worked for me for a while.  You may have a browser plugin or the OS may be interfering here.